# Обработка значения из localStorage начинается раньше, чем она присваивается в вызываемой перед этим функции.

Tags: javascript

Есть подобие контроллера, который вызывает функцию отрисовки страницы авторизации и навешивает функцию на кнопку входа, по нажатию на которую я должна проверить по значениям из формы, существует такой пользователь или нет.

```
function controller()
{
    drawLoginPage();
    document.getElementById("enter").onclick = function()
    {
        const USER = document.getElementById("username").value;
        const PASSWORD = document.getElementById("password").value;
        if (USER == '' || PASSWORD == '')
                alert("Wrong login or password"); 
        else {
                window.localStorage.removeItem('userIsFind');
                findTheUser(USER, PASSWORD);
                let FindUser = localStorage['userIsFind'] || "false";
                if (FindUser == "true")
                {
                    document.getElementById("loginFormId").remove();
                    createStorePageForUser(Log);
                }
                else alert("Wrong login or password");
            }
    }  
}
```

Функция поиска пользователя реализована как чтение данных из JSONа, и, когда соответствие по полям было найдено или перелопачу весь файл логинов и паролей, но ничего не найду, в хранилище записываю, был ли найден данный пользователь.

```
function findTheUser(Log, Pas)
{
    fetch("Users.json")
    .then(function(response)
    {
        return response.json();
    })
        .then(function(data) 
        {
            let currentUser = 0;
            while ( currentUser < data.length && (data[currentUser].username !=  Log && data[currentUser].password !=  Pas  ))  currentUser++;
            localStorage['userIsFind'] = String(currentUser != data.length);   
        });
}
```

Загвоздка в том, что моя обработка в контроллере заканчивается раньше, чем я проверю данного пользователя. Т.е. он сначала выполнит let FindUser = localStorage['userIsFind'] || "false"; if (FindUser == "true"){...}, а потом уже пойдет по JSONу. Подскажите, как решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте функцию async function controller() - асинхронной и внутри тела функции дожидайтесь окончания асинхронного запроса await findTheUser(USER, PASSWORD); Так как запрос json является асинхронным, он выпадает из потока вызовов, и будет выполнен позже, когда придет json. И еще, вы уверены что отдавать на фронт всех юзеров с паролями , это хорошая идея? Лучше отдать поиск пользователя на серверную часть.

Comment: +1 к глупым вопросам пишу сразу  await findTheUser(USER, PASSWORD) - жалуется Expected ; but found findTheUser
Хоть где-то он находится :D

Comment: @ Колесник Татьяна вам необходимо немного переписать код и почитать про функционал async/await. в итоге мы можем получить json уже внутри события клика const jsonData = await fetch("Users.json"); и уже операции поиска проводить с объектом jsonData. Или сделать findTheUser - асинхронной и производить поиск внутри нее так же ожидая await fetch("Users.json");